# Ember.js model save sends no data to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ember.js, ember-data

I'm currently building a small demo app using Ember.JS and NodeJS with Express. I've knocked up a simple model and have created an action to save it.

The component has a property called `recipe`, which is an instance of a model I've defined. The save action is as simple as:

```
save() {
  this.get('recipe').save();
}
```

Looking at my network tab in Chrome dev tools, I can see the data in the request payload. However, I can't access the data in my Node app. I've logged the full `req` object and my data isn't there anywhere.

I have a feeling this is to do with the fact that Ember uses the PATCH verb, whereas I'd expect it to use PUT or POST.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I fixed the issue by using `DS.RESTAdapter` as opposed to `DS.JSONAPIAdapter`. The `RESTAdapter` uses `PUT` when you save a record while `JSONAPIAdapter` uses `PATCH`. I suspect there's some issue in the implementation of `PATCH` in either Ember or Express.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: Without seeing the code it is difficult to give you a definitive answer.*

The JSON API specification defines, that updating a resource is done with the PATCH verb. (http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-updating)

If you chose to use this adapter, you will have to define the appropriate routes in your Express app. Without seeing it, I'd suggest to define the route for PUT and PATCH with the same callback and you'll be fine.

For example:

```
router.put('/:id', controller.update);
router.patch('/:id', controller.update);
```

Overriding the HTTP verb in the adapter is not that easy at the moment (Ember Data 2.4). A possible head would be to override the `updateRecord` method of the adapter. (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.4.0/addon/adapters/json-api.js#L115-L133)

Comment: I should have been more clear. I've already defined the PATCH and PUT routes in my Express app, however the `req.body` object is empty whenever I save the model in my Ember code. The route's definitely being called okay, just the needed data isn't sent along with it.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: Without seeing the code it is difficult to give you a definitive answer.*

You're not receiving the request payload because the `'Content-Type'` header has not been set properly.

The `JSONAPIAdapter` for Ember sends requests with the `'Content-Type'` header set to `'application/vnd.api+json'`. You'll need to set this in `body-parser` like so:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));
```